# Google Таблицы. Как к выделеным ячейкам добавить число?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Появилась необходимость добавить к определенным ячейкам одно и тоже число (или умножить выделенные ячейки на число) без использования формул. Знаю, что такая возможность есть в Excel, но в Google Таблицах не удалось ее найти. Можете что-то подсказать?

Comment: Похоже, в `Спецвставке` в *Google*-таблицах такого нет. Если ячейки в неразрывном диапазоне, в свободной области таблицы вписать нужную формулу со ссылкой на ячейку (`=D5+4`, `=D5*2`), копировать полученній результат, спецвставкой вставить в  дипазон значения.

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно будет добавлять одно и то же число регулярно. то есть с использованием обычного =D5+4, мне нужно будет каждый раз переписывать D5

Comment: Вариант2 - макрос на JS

Comment: Уже кое-как реализовал, спасибо за совет)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовали? Может на сегодняшний день упростилась эта задача? Надо в определенные ячейки добавлять +1.